# In Android, error "could not find com.android.support:support-v4:22.2.20" while integrate AdMob into my App

Tags: android, admob

I want to integrate AdMob into my app. If I add the following line in the dependencies

```
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:8.3.0'
```

then I get the following error:

```
Error:A problem occurred configuring project ':app'.
 Could not resolve all dependencies for configuration ':app:_debugCompile'.
    Could not find com.android.support:support-v4:22.2.0.
     Searched in the following locations:
         https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/android/support/support-v4/22.2.0/support-v4-22.2.0.pom
         https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/android/support/support-v4/22.2.0/support-v4-22.2.0.aar
         file:/C:/Users/narayan/AppData/Local/Android/sdk/extras/android/m2repository/com/android/support/support-v4/22.2.0/support-v4-22.2.0.pom
         file:/C:/Users/narayan/AppData/Local/Android/sdk/extras/android/m2repository/com/android/support/support-v4/22.2.0/support-v4-22.2.0.aar
         file:/C:/Users/narayan/AppData/Local/Android/sdk/extras/google/m2repository/com/android/support/support-v4/22.2.0/support-v4-22.2.0.pom
         file:/C:/Users/narayan/AppData/Local/Android/sdk/extras/google/m2repository/com/android/support/support-v4/22.2.0/support-v4-22.2.0.aar
     Required by:
         AncientGame:app:unspecified  com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.0.0
         AncientGame:app:unspecified  com.google.android.gms:play-services:7.5.0  com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:7.5.0
    Could not find com.android.support:support-v4:22.2.0.
     Searched in the following locations:
         https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/android/support/support-v4/22.2.0/support-v4-22.2.0.pom
         https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/android/support/support-v4/22.2.0/support-v4-22.2.0.aar
         file:/C:/Users/narayan/AppData/Local/Android/sdk/extras/android/m2repository/com/android/support/support-v4/22.2.0/support-v4-22.2.0.pom
         file:/C:/Users/narayan/AppData/Local/Android/sdk/extras/android/m2repository/com/android/support/support-v4/22.2.0/support-v4-22.2.0.aar
         file:/C:/Users/narayan/AppData/Local/Android/sdk/extras/google/m2repository/com/android/support/support-v4/22.2.0/support-v4-22.2.0.pom
         file:/C:/Users/narayan/AppData/Local/Android/sdk/extras/google/m2repository/com/android/support/support-v4/22.2.0/support-v4-22.2.0.aar
     Required by:
         AncientGame:app:unspecified  AncientGame:BaseGameUtils:unspecified
    Could not find com.android.support:support-v4:22.2.0.
     Searched in the following locations:
         https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/android/support/support-v4/22.2.0/support-v4-22.2.0.pom
         https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/android/support/support-v4/22.2.0/support-v4-22.2.0.aar
         file:/C:/Users/narayan/AppData/Local/Android/sdk/extras/android/m2repository/com/android/support/support-v4/22.2.0/support-v4-22.2.0.pom
         file:/C:/Users/narayan/AppData/Local/Android/sdk/extras/android/m2repository/com/android/support/support-v4/22.2.0/support-v4-22.2.0.aar
         file:/C:/Users/narayan/AppData/Local/Android/sdk/extras/google/m2repository/com/android/support/support-v4/22.2.0/support-v4-22.2.0.pom
         file:/C:/Users/narayan/AppData/Local/Android/sdk/extras/google/m2repository/com/android/support/support-v4/22.2.0/support-v4-22.2.0.aar
     Required by:
         AncientGame:app:unspecified  com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:8.3.0  com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement:8.3.0
```

How can I solve this. Please help me!!

Answer (score 0):

You receive that error because your `Android Support Repository` is not updated.

To resolve the issue:

- Open SDK Manager
- Select `Extras > Android Support Repository`
- Press `Install packages...`